# Ansible - Remove login window in CentOS 6

Tags: regex, ansible, centos, centos6

I wrote a hardening script for CentOS workstation and I'm stuck on a process for Cent6 systems where I want to remove the login screen and have the user enter their login ID.

The file is:

```
/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml
```

Here is the line I am trying to edit:

```
<entry name="disable_user_list" mtime="1558109430" type="schema" stype="bool" owner="gdm-simple-greeter" gettext_domain="gdm">
  <local_schema locale="C" short_desc="Do not show known users in the login window">
     <default type="bool" value="false"/>
     <longdesc>Set to true to disable showing known users in the login window.</longdesc>
   </local_schema>
</entry>
```

The line I need to edit is:

```
value="false"
```

to:

```
value="true"
```

Because there are more than one "disabe_user_list" in this file, I am not sure how I can use `inlinefile` option to edit this specific field. I'm pretty sure there might be a regex I could use but I couldn't figure it out.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html?

Comment: Using regex for xml always pops this in my mind :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2123530

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR;

Here is a possible solution for you

```yaml
- xml:
    path: /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml
    xpath: "/entry[@name='disable_user_list']/local_schema[@short_desc='Do not show known users in the login window']/default[@type='bool']"
    attribute: value
    value: "true"
```

---

The [`xml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html) module seems to be a better alternative than doing a regex.

This could be a solution for you, but, of course, you'll have to validate this with the other `disabe_user_list` entries that you might have in your file.

The XPath in this playbook consider that this entry is unique based on the facts that:

1. the `entry` node is named `disable_user_list`
2. the `local_schema` node under `entry` have a `short_desc` reading `Do not show known users in the login window``
3. the `default` node under `local_schema` is of `type`: `bool`

Based on that, the task would target the `value` attribute and set it to `true`.

Given this playbook

```yaml
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - xml:
        path: /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml
        xpath: "/entry[@name='disable_user_list']/local_schema[@short_desc='Do not show known users in the login window']/default[@type='bool']"
        attribute: value
        value: "true"
```

Here is an example of execution

```
cat /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml && ansible-playbook play.yml && cat /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/\%gconf-tree.xml
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry name="disable_user_list" mtime="1558109430" type="schema" stype="bool" owner="gdm-simple-greeter" gettext_domain="gdm">
  <local_schema locale="C" short_desc="Do not show known users in the login window">
     <default type="bool" value="false"/>
     <longdesc>Set to true to disable showing known users in the login window.</longdesc>
   </local_schema>
</entry>
```

```
PLAY [local] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [xml] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [local]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry name="disable_user_list" mtime="1558109430" type="schema" stype="bool" owner="gdm-simple-greeter" gettext_domain="gdm">
  <local_schema locale="C" short_desc="Do not show known users in the login window">
     <default type="bool" value="true"/>
     <longdesc>Set to true to disable showing known users in the login window.</longdesc>
   </local_schema>
</entry>
```